# Edit Calendar webpart with JQuery on page load

Tags: web-part, jquery

I've been struggling for a few days now trying to solve this problem. I have a calendar app part on my page that is taking up too much space. The requirements for the calendar are that it just displays the first 3 letters of the day i.e. MON in place of MONDAY etc.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9GG8j/) I've created this JS fiddle with a similar structure to how the dates are displayed in the calendar web part however if I try place this code in a Javascript editor web part on my page it doesn't change the text.

I've tried putting the code in the master page itself but that didn't load or run at all.

Any help would be appreciated

Regards
~Donald Dunlop

Comment: Did you try debugging through browser developer tools, to check whether the script you have written is getting hit when the page is loaded?

Comment: Just ran it using that, got '$' is undefined. The solution was to put the script tag for JQuery in the master page's <head> tags.

Using the browser developer tools I found that the JQuery was not firing because '$' was not defined. The cause of that error is that the script tag importing JQuery was in the <body></body> tags of the master page and not in the <head></head> tags.

Moving the script to the head tag loads JQuery before building elements on the page and defines the '$' operator.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to  [Msounthar](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/users/19069/msounthar) the solution was found using IE's developer tools script tab. When the page was reloaded I got a message stating that "Element '$' is undefined". A quick search revealed that this was caused by the  tag that loads JQuery not being in the right position.

Moving the  tag into the  tag of the site collection's master page loaded JQuery before the page and then when the script was called in a Script Editor web part the code executed without fail.

Answer (score 0):

You must have your JavaScript code that modifies the HTML inside special jQuery function that runs after page HTML is rendered. More info of .ready() [here](http://api.jquery.com/ready/).

```
$(function() {    
    //Your code    
});
```

Comment: Hi, the issue was not that as you can see in the JSFiddle link the code works without issue, the problem was that JQuery wasn't initialised on the master page before the function ran